# Facebook defaults purchase events not tracking

Tags: android, facebook, events, in-app-purchase, subscription

We have implemented android fb sdk to track app events .. custom events are triggering fine .. install events (MOBILE_APP_INSTALL) are working fine but default app events like fb_mobile_purchase, fb_mobile_initiated_checkout, which related to purchase  events not triggering. In test events console also not showing. any one can help to identify this issue?

sdk initiated like below in Application :-

```
FacebookSdk.setAutoInitEnabled(true)
FacebookSdk.fullyInitialize()
FacebookSdk.setAutoLogAppEventsEnabled(true);
FacebookSdk.setAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled(true)
```

I need to view all purchase events like fb_mobile_initiated_checkout, fb_mobile_purchase in facebook events.